# Jasmine: after using callFake, how can you revert to the original function?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Say that you have `spyOn(obj, 'method').and.callFake(fn);`. How can you subsequently revert `obj.method` back to it's original function?

Use case: if you are doing a `callFake` in a big `beforeEach` and want to use the original method for one of your test cases, but the fake in the rest.

**test.js**

```
var obj = {
    method: function () {
        return 'original';
    },
}

module.exports = obj;
```

**testSpec.js**

```
var obj = require('../test.js');

describe('obj.method', function () {
    it('should return "original" by default', function () {
    expect(obj.method()).toBe('original');
  });

  it('should return "fake" when faked', function () {
    spyOn(obj, 'method').and.callFake(function () {
      return 'fake';
    });

    expect(obj.method()).toBe('fake');
  });

  it('should return "original" when reverted after being faked', function () {
    spyOn(obj, 'method').and.callFake(function () {
      return 'fake';
    });

    // what code can be written here to get the test to pass?

    expect(obj.method()).toBe('original');
  });
});
```

I'm using Jasmine v2.5.2.

---

Edit: Well, I suppose you could just write:

```
obj.method = function () {
  return 'original';
};
```

but that feels way too not-DRY. Is there something jasmine-based like `obj.method.revertToOriginal()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `callThrough()` on spied method to revert it to basic function.

```js
var obj = {
  method: function() {
    return 'original'
  }
}

describe('obj.method', function() {
  it('should return "original" by default', function() {
    expect(obj.method()).toBe('original');
  });

  it('should return "fake" when faked', function() {
    spyOn(obj, 'method').and.callFake(function() {
      return 'fake';
    });

    expect(obj.method()).toBe('fake');
  });

  it('should return "original" when reverted after being faked', function() {
    spyOn(obj, 'method').and.callFake(function() {
      return 'fake';
    });

    obj.method.and.callThrough() // method for revert spy

    expect(obj.method()).toBe('original');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
```